# How to form validate a no model property in angular

Tags: angular, validation, angular7, angular-ngmodel

I have 2 text box in angular html name and date..
But i didnt mapped this with any model.
How to do validation for this?

When i google all validations are based on ngModel only. How to do validation for a component property which is not a model property?

Thanks in Advance.

edit:

```
 <form #dartForm='ngForm' (ngSubmit)='onSubmit(inputName.value, inputDate.value)'>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col col-12">
          <div class="form-group col col-6">
            <label for="username">Name: </label>
            <select #inputName class="form-control" id="username">
              <option>SELECT</option>
              <option>Monicka</option>
              <option>Hema</option>
              <option>Ramesh</option>
              <option>Madhavan</option>
              <option>Aadhavan</option>
              <option>Madhan</option>
              <option>Prasanth</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col col-6">
            <label for="date">Date:</label>
            <input type="text" #inputDate class="form-control" id="date">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type='submit'>Search</button>
      </div>
    </form>


export class PlannerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dartService: DartService) { }
  curDate = new Date();
  name: string;
  date: Date = this.curDate;
  darts: Dart[] = [];
```

In this i want to validate name and date...

Comment: What are you doing with those data then?

Comment: Its a serch criteria. so only am validationg this. But i didnt create model for search criteria alone..

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: check updated que

Comment: why dont use a template- or model-driven forms?

Comment: Use binding, on submit call validation for each bound prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just use what Angular has to offer:

- Template forms
- Reactive forms

Pick your choice. My personal preference always go to reactive forms as we've built a library at work called [ngx-sub-form](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form) that gives us plenty of advantages like type safety, breaking down form into sub forms, access nested errors and more.

To build the thing you mentioned in your post, I'd do it in the following way:

- Create a "smart" component which will retrieve your names (from a server, local storage, a store, whatever)
- Create a "form" component which will handle all the form part and only return the expect object once it's been saved

Here's a live demo of how to do that with `ngx-sub-form`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-knhgk5

Now let's give some details:

First of all, let's write our interface!

**planner.interface.ts**

```
export interface Planner {
  name: string;
  date: string;
}
```

Then let's create the smart component:

**planner-container.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-planner-container',
  templateUrl: './planner-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planner-container.component.css']
})
export class PlannerContainerComponent {
  // those names would probably be fetched from a server
  // but hardcoded for the sake of simplicity in the demo
  public names: string[] = [
    'Monicka',
    'Hema',
    'Ramesh',
    'Madhavan',
    'Aadhavan',
    'Madhan',
    'Prasanth',
  ];

  public save(value: Planner): void {
    // todo: do whatever you want here
    // this method will be run only once the form is valid and sent
    console.log('Form has been sent!');
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

The smart component would be in charge of retrieving the names from a service, and manage what to do once the form is valid and sent. That's it. It shouldn't even be aware of how the form is implemented.

Most important part: The form

**planner-form.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-planner-form',
  templateUrl: './planner-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./planner-form.component.css']
})
export class PlannerFormComponent extends NgxSubFormComponent<Planner> {
  @Input() public names: string[];

  @Output() public save: EventEmitter<Planner> = new EventEmitter();

  public getFormControls(): Controls<Planner> {
    return {
      name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      date: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    }
  }

  public send(): void {
    this.save.emit(this.formGroupValues);
  }
}
```

Few things to notice here:

- The component extends `NgxSubFormComponent`
- It is type safe because we pass our type to the parent class `NgxSubFormComponent<Planner>`
- We define the form controls using the `getFormControls` provided by `NgxSubFormComponent` it's also there that we can pass our validators

The form's view:

**planner-form.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="send()">
  <select [formControlName]="formControlNames.name">
    <option value="">Select someone</option>
    <option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">{{ name }}</option>
  </select>

  <input type="date" placeholder="Date" [formControlName]="formControlNames.date">

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="formGroup.invalid">Save</button>
</form>


<!-- debug -->
(CF console for output once the form is saved!)

<hr>

<p>Form value:</p>
<pre>{{ formGroupValues | json }}</pre>

<hr>

<p>Form errors</p>
<pre>{{ formGroupErrors | json }}</pre>
```

Notes:

- `formGroup` is defined by the library and simply gives you access to... the form group!
- `formControlNames` gives you access to all the form control names but in a type safe way and if you write a bad variable name typescript will pick it up (while compiling with AOT)
- `formGroupValues` gives you access to the values (final object that we want to send!)
- `formGroupErrors` gives you access to the errors so you can conditionally display messages based on that

For more about ngx-sub-form, visit the Github page https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form and read the Readme, everything should be correctly explained with a lot of examples too in the `/src` folder!

Live demo of your example: https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form

**Edit:**

If you want to go further, I've just published a blog post to explain a lot of things about forms and ngx-sub-form here https://dev.to/maxime1992/building-scalable-robust-and-type-safe-forms-with-angular-3nf9

Comment: Is this for a template driven form? I am new to angular, please reply.

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? ngx-sub-form? If so, I've never tested it on template driven form, only with a reactive form. That said it uses a ControlValueAccessor behind the scenes so it may be working just fine with template driven forms (?!) but I've never tested it